# Почему элементы ElementTree - это falsy-объекты?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

До этого момента не пользовался `xml.etree`, и столкнулся со странной вещью

```py
if some_tag.find('other_tag'):
    print('Я существую')
```

В таком виде эта конструкиця не работает и приходится делать вот так

```py
if some_tag.find('other_tag') is not None:
    print('Я существую')
```

Есть ли в этом какой-то глубокий смысл? Почему это реализовано так? Для чего существующий в структуре xml объект сделали falsy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Должно работать, т.к. [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) или вернет объект или `None`, если тот не был найден.

А проверка `if` с объектом обычно возвращает `True`, если тот существует, но тут есть важный момент, то, что возвращается при `if some_tag.find('other_tag')` зависит от магического метода `__bool__` у объекта (того что [find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) вернет).

Т.е. `None` в любом случае будет ассоциирован с `False`, а вот как будет ассоциирован объект зависит от того, что он вернет в `__bool__`. Поэтому, наиболее точно проверять как `is not None`.

---

**PS.**

Наглядно про `__bool__`:

```
class MyFalse:
    pass

print(bool(MyFalse()))
if MyFalse():
    print('[1]')
# True
# [1]

class MyFalse:
    def __bool__(self):
        return False

print(bool(MyFalse()))
if MyFalse():
    print('[2]')
# False
```

---

**PPS.**

А так у меня не повторилось, но я вам верю:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.fromstring("""\
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
</data>
""")

if tree.find('other_tag'):
    print('Я существую / other_tag')

if tree.find('other_tag') is not None:
    print('Я существую / other_tag')

if tree.find('country'):
    print('Я существую / country')

if tree.find('country') is not None:
    print('Я существую / country')
```

Результат:

```
Я существую / country
Я существую / country
```

Comment: Хороший ответ, +1 с моей стороны!